# SAP HANA Connection with Ionic App(Error in browser /node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js)

Tags: node.js, jdbc, ionic4, hana, node-java

I am trying to create SAP HANA DB connection for my ionic application.
The methods,I have tried :

- 1) installing @naxmefy/jdbc
  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@naxmefy/jdbc) 
  2) installing standard
  jdbc (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc) 
  3) installing hdb along
  with @sap/hana-client. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/hdb)

Unfortunetely, they all had similar errors in common.

Just by installing them caused "cant resolve fs,crpyto,http ..etc" error on compiler.
I tried to solve this issue by adding "node: fs:'true'" to my commonjs or configuring my package.json afterwards it was compiled successfully but browser was giving me and error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js".

I searched for a long time but couldnt get my browser  to work.Did anyone try hana connection in ionic ?
Any help/idea would be very  much appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it can not be done on front-end so it should be executed with nodejs .
The link below helped me to configure nodejs accordingly.And the one below could help with sap hana connection. Good luck!!

https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-an-ionic-application-with-a-nodejs-backend/

https://www.syedhussim.com/hana-db/connect-to-hana-db-using-nodejs.html